# Purescript Halogen, side effect (random number)

Tags: random, state, purescript, halogen

In a PureScript Halogen project, I would like to set the state to a random number, but how do I extract the value? The normal

```
r <- randomInt 1 10
```

does not compile when it's inside the eval function.

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Random (randomInt, RANDOM)
import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML.Events.Indexed as HE
import Halogen.HTML.Indexed as HH
import Halogen.Util (runHalogenAff, awaitBody)

type State = { n::Int }

initialState :: State
initialState = { n: 3}

data Query a = NewRandom a

ui :: forall e. H.Component { n :: Int } Query e
ui =
    H.component { render, eval }
    where
    render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
    render state =
        HH.button
            [ HE.onClick $ HE.input_ NewRandom ]
            [ HH.text $ show state.n ]


    eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query e
    eval (NewRandom next) = do
        H.modify (\state -> state { n=12 } )

        --I'd like to set n to a random number
        --but I don't know how.
        --let r = randomInt 1 10
        --H.modify (\state -> state { n=r } )
        pure next

main :: Eff (H.HalogenEffects ()) Unit
main =
    runHalogenAff do
    body <- awaitBody
    H.runUI ui initialState body
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an appropriate monad with your `ComponentDSL` (where you have the `e` type var currently) to make it possible, and then you can use `H.fromEff` to lift the `randomInt`:

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Random (randomInt, RANDOM)
import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML.Events.Indexed as HE
import Halogen.HTML.Indexed as HH
import Halogen.Util (runHalogenAff, awaitBody)

type State = { n::Int }

initialState :: State
initialState = { n: 3}

data Query a = NewRandom a

ui :: forall eff. H.Component { n :: Int } Query (Aff (random :: RANDOM | eff))
ui =
    H.component { render, eval }
    where
    render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
    render state =
        HH.button
            [ HE.onClick $ HE.input_ NewRandom ]
            [ HH.text $ show state.n ]


    eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query (Aff (random :: RANDOM | eff))
    eval (NewRandom next) = do
        r <- H.fromEff $ randomInt 1 10
        H.modify (\state -> state { n=r } )
        pure next

main :: forall eff. Eff (H.HalogenEffects (random :: RANDOM | eff)) Unit
main =
    runHalogenAff do
    body <- awaitBody
    H.runUI ui initialState body
```

(Aside: If you're doing effectful things, even if you only need `Eff`, it's easiest to use `Aff` as the `ComponentDSL` monad, as when you use `runUI` it expects it to be `Aff` - it is possible to change the monad, using `interpret` in the `Halogen.Component` module, but since you'd just be using `interpret liftAff` there anyway, you may as well go straight to `Aff`.)

Take a look at the ["Non-state effects" section of the guide](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/v0.11.0/GUIDE.md#non-state-effects), or the [AJAX example](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/tree/v0.11.0/examples/ajax) for more details on running effects in `eval`.